An Integration Used in Proving property of Bernstein Bases
$\newcommand{\bicoeff}[2]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\\#2\end{pmatrix}}$
$\newcommand{\brstbasis}[2]{b^{#1}_{#2}}$
$\newcommand{\posintset}{\mathbb{Z}^{+}}$
I am writing some document on Bernstein polynomials. Specifically, I want to write the proof for the following statement: Let $n, k \in \posintset$ and $0 \leq k \leq n$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1} \brstbasis{n}{k}\left(t\right) \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{n + 1}.
\end{equation*}
Below is my proof:
\begin{equation*}
\brstbasis{n}{k}\left(t\right) = \bicoeff{n}{k} t^{k} \left(1 - t\right)^{n - k}.
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1} \brstbasis{n}{k}\left(t\right) \mathrm{d}t = \bicoeff{n}{k} \int_{0}^{1} t^{k} \left(1 - t\right)^{n - k} \mathrm{d}t.
\end{equation*}
Somehow, I forgot how to integrate $\int_{0}^{1} t^{k} \left(1 - t\right)^{n - k} \mathrm{d}t$ (have been out of college for many years...). Can someone help me?

For $0\le k<n$ you could do integration by parts $$\int_0^1 t^k(1-t)^{n-k},dt=\left.\frac{1}{k+1}t^{k+1}(1-t)^{n-k}\right\rvert_0^1+\frac{n-k}{k+1}\int_0^1t^{k+1}(1-t)^{n-k-1},dt=\=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\int_0^1 t^{k+1}(1-t)^{n-k-1},dt$$ and eventually obtain $$\int_0^1 t^k(1-t)^{n-k},dt=\left(\prod_{j=k}^{n-1}\frac{n-j}{j+1}\right)\int_0^1 t^n,dt$$

Yes, this is correct. Thanks!

Recall the Bata Function $$
\int_0^1 t^k(1-t)^{n-k} d t=B(k+1, n-k+1),$$
then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1} b_{k}^{n}\left(t\right) \mathrm{d}t & =\binom{n}{k} B(k+1)(n-k+1) \\
& =\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \frac{\Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(n-k+1)}{\Gamma(n+2)} \\
& =\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \frac{k!(n-k)!}{(n+1)!} \\
& =\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{aligned}
$$
